# Photon Entanglement using SPDC

Tags: entanglement, resource-request, spdc

Are there any good references where from I can learn about photon entanglement using spontaneous parametric down-conversion (SPDC)?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Quantum Computing SE. For a  start, you may have a look at the [Wikipedia page on SPDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion) and the links therein.

Comment: Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! As different sources go into varying levels of detail on this, it would be useful to know what your background is as well as the level you want this aimed at - the more details we have, the better/more appropriate the resource we can give you!

Comment: I'm postgraduate student. I've been working on Quantum Computation (theoretical) works from one year. Now I'd like to realise Quantum Entanglement experimentally. So I was thinking of doing the experiment using a 2nd order NLO Crystal. Plan is to have Entangled photon using SPDC. But I don't have any knowledge on the experimental aspects. So I want to study about the SPDC and how the photon entanglement is related to it (theoretical explanation).